# Push object in array of objects but only if the object property is unique

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I want is to push all objects from arrayToPush into array but only the ones that has different id. So in this case I would like to have an array with id's 111,222,333,444,555 and do not push object in arrayToPush that has id 333. How can i achieve that? Thanks in advance

```
var array = [
   {title: 'Something', id: 111},
   {title: 'Something 2', id: 222},
   {title: 'Something 3', id: 333}
]

var arrayToPush = [
   {title: 'Something 4', id: 333},
   {title: 'Something 5', id: 444},
   {title: 'Something 6', id: 555}
]

for(var i = 0; i < arrayToPush.length; i++) {
   array.push(arrayToPush[i])
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show us the code where you have did some attempt to achieve the behaviour.

Comment: I have edited the question, this is what i have tried and got all objects from arrayToPush into the array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over arrayToPush and check if the object exists on array with array.find()

```
arrayToPush.forEach(x => {
    if (!array.find(e => e.id === x.id)) {
        array.push(x)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this is works. Is there any way of doing this in ES5 syntax?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to filter the `ArrayToPush` to eliminate the existing elements and then contact both of them using the spread operator :

```js
var array = [
  { title: "Something", id: 111 },
  { title: "Something 2", id: 222 },
  { title: "Something 3", id: 333 }
];

var arrayToPush = [
  { title: "Something 4", id: 333 },
  { title: "Something 5", id: 444 },
  { title: "Something 6", id: 555 }
];

var filtered = arrayToPush.filter(a => !array.find(b => b.id === a.id));

var result = [...array, ...filtered];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know which ids you have in the **array**:

```
const arrayIds =  array.map(({ id }) => id); // [111, 222, 333]
```

Then you need to filter the **arrayToPush**, so you loop through the **arrayToPush** and filter those that are not included the the **array**:

```
const filteredArrayToPush = arrayToPush.filter(({ id }) => !arrayIds.includes(id));
```

And then concat both arrays **array** and **filteredArrayToPush**:

```
array = [...array, ...filteredArrayToPush];
```